# Auto-complete Text box fill

Tags: jquery, html, cordova

I'm following [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Lq5fagdb/) source.

In my case I need to fill *data source* from a table in *MySQL* database. For example that table contains `id` and `product_name`, so when I start typing in the *text box* available product with typed letter should show and when I choose a product then I need to do another task by referring the *id* of selected *product*.

Note: Im trying to create a mobile app with HTML5 and jQuery using PhoneGap

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: @user3154108 How to fill the datasource with table from mysql

Comment: You prolly should use ajax and sql?

Comment: @user3154108 How to ?

Comment: @user3154108 How to store id,productname in a variable and show that in  a autocomplete source?

Comment: You really need to give more information in your question.

Comment: What you need is like autocomplete feature of jquery. Check this out ; https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: @shamaleyte Actually I ended up with that widget, but its filling only a single column . How Can I fill the same with 2 column for example `Product Name` and `Product_Id` here `Product Name` is only visible to the user and `Product_Id` is the value identifier for the selected `Product Name`

Comment: Ok if you checked the example provided in jquery link page,  you will see the "var availableTags" that is full of  words that will be served to the user as an autocomplete option.  First you should make sure that you "autocomplete" array is full of the strings ( Product Name, Product_ID , and son ) .  Second  step is importing the jquery-ui.css. It is actually the key step for having the options as given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AJAX. On keyUp/KeyPress event trigger a call to DB passing the id which will return the results. You then need to display those using jQuery autocomplete or some other API